# Linux VSFTPD : Jail a "Specific SFTP User" to its home?

Tags: linux, sftp, home-directory, jail, vsftpd

I'm using both Redhat and CentOS. I previously wanted to jail a "Specific User" to its home. Then i got it by following [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18778004/linux-vsftpd-jail-a-specific-user-to-its-home#18779105).

When the user *(lets say, using FileZilla)* use:

- Protocol: `FTP`

.. it is fine!

But again there, when the user connects with:

- Protocol: `SFTP` *(in the FileZilla setting)*

.. the Jailing for that Specific User is NOT working anymore. Can still browse through.

How can i make it to have:

- In `vsFTPd`, jail a Specific User to its home when using `Protocol: SFTP`.

Thank you!

Comment: StackOverflow is NOT for server administration questions. You keep posting questions that are offtopic here.

Answer (score 2):

Hi yes sftp works with ssh configuration on port 22, http:/thegeekstuff.com/2012/03/chroot-sftp-setup would make you jailroot the users. You have to modify ssh configuration file to jail root the users.

Thanks & Regards,
Alok

Comment: Still can not :S Am i supposed to `stop` the `vsftpd`?

Comment: Thanks WORKED !!, it seems there is no need to vsftpd or others ftp servers in this case right ?